# Invoking a method on an object

Tags: python, c, embedded-language

Given a PyObject* pointing to a python object, how do I invoke one of the object methods? The documentation never gives an example of this:

```
PyObject* obj = ....
PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "An arg");
PyObject* method = PyWHATGOESHERE(obj, "foo");
PyObject* ret = PyWHATGOESHERE(obj, method, args);
if (!ret) {
   // check error...
}
```

This would be the equivalent of

```
>>> ret = obj.foo("An arg")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
PyObject* obj = ....
PyObject *ret = PyObject_CallMethod(obj, "foo", "(s)", "An arg");
if (!ret) {
   // check error...
}
```

Read up on the [Python C API documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html). In this case, you want the [object protocol](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html).

> ```
> PyObject* PyObject_CallMethod(PyObject *o, char *method, char *format, ...)
> ```
>
> Return value: New reference.
>
> Call the method named method of object o with a variable number of C
>   arguments. The C arguments are
>   described by a `Py_BuildValue()` format
>   string that should produce a tuple.
>   The format may be `NULL`, indicating
>   that no arguments are provided.
>   Returns the result of the call on
>   success, or `NULL` on failure. This is
>   the equivalent of the Python
>   expression `o.method(args)`. Note that
>   if you only pass `PyObject * args`,
>   `PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs()` is a
>   faster alternative.

And

> ```
> PyObject* PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(PyObject *o, PyObject *name, ..., NULL)
> ```
>
> Return value: New reference.
>
> Calls a method of the object `o`, where the name of the method is given
>   as a Python string object in name. It
>   is called with a variable number of
>   `PyObject*` arguments. The arguments are
>   provided as a variable number of
>   parameters followed by `NULL`. Returns
>   the result of the call on success, or
>   `NULL` on failure.

Comment: Knowing what "Object protocol" is was the problem. Also, I was looking for invoke for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your example would be:

```
PyObject* ret = PyObject_CallMethod(obj, "foo", "(s)", "An arg");
```

Comment: I know its 7 years too late but what does the (s) mean in the format arg.?

Comment: It's the same format string as used by Py_BuildValue: the parens means it will build a tuple, the s means the next argument ("An arg") will be a C char* string, converted to a Python string.  The tuple is used as the positional arguments of the function, so we are passing one string.

Comment: What if I want to pass an c array as a  list of strings or list of doubles such as, `['kks', 'sss','www','sse']` or `[323.9, 32, 443, 434.8,56.6]`?